# Javascript export a new object instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export utilities = {
    assignOptions: function(newOption, callback) {
        //Incorrect 'this' context on second binding
        this.props.updateOptions((prevOptions) => Object.assign({}, prevOptions, newOption), callback);
    }
};

export const FirstComponent = (WrappedComponent) => class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);   

        utilities.assignOptions = utilities.assignOptions.bind(this);
        utilities.assignOptions("test"); //'this' context is FirstComponent
    }
};

export const SecondComponent = (WrappedComponent) => class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);   

        utilities.assignOptions = utilities.assignOptions.bind(this);
        utilities.assignOptions("test2"); //'this' context is still FirstComponent instead of SecondComponent
    }
};
```

It seems to be the same instance that's getting exported and so the bindings aren't working.
How do I export a new instance each time?

Comment: That's kind of an odd way of approaching a `utilities` function. Could you maybe explain the use case? Passing a component's context around like that can complicate debugging. Why not be more "pure" and be more declarative? It almost looks like you're trying to create a high order component (attach certain props to a component, not usually accepted). If that's the case, I recommend looking at an implementation of one.

Comment: @ZekeDroid These actually are HOC's, I edited the code. Both components use the same syntax when updating the parent state via that `updateOptions()` so I don't really want to have to write `Object.assign` 100 times in my code and would rather use a utility function like above to share the common code.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to focus on the bug you're seeing and not on the way you're attacking this use case. I'm thinking it has to do with how context is shared in normal objects vs ES6 classes. I don't know that you can use `this` like you're using it here. Why not make proper HOCs instead? As in, a component wrapped in a component?

Comment: @ZekeDroid Not sure I understand how this would mean I don't have to write `this.props.updateOptions((prevOptions) => Object.assign({}, prevOptions, newOption)` everywhere. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Of course. Let me add it as an answer because I need proper markdown.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely how JS handles context within objects vs ES6 classes. An easy way to do prop injection like what I think you're attempting is to create an HOC that will wrap your components:

```
function wrapComponent(ComponentToWrap) {
  return class WrappedComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <ComponentToWrap {...this.props}/>
    }
  }
}
```

This is a simplistic example but think that you can use as much logic as you'd like to inject whatever props you'd like into each `WrappedComponent`.